# maximize the maximum value of a linear optimization

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Here is my problem, first, $v$ is the optimal value of a LP problem
$$
    v = \max_w w^TF\beta 
$$
subject to 
$$
    w \ge 0 \\
    Aw = b \\
$$

Then I want to find the coefficient $\beta$ that maximize $v$
$$
    \beta^* = argmax_{\beta} \ \ v
$$

Comment: Linear functions are unbounded.

Comment: You must have some constraints on $\beta$, otherwise you can just multiply $\beta$ by any positive constant and your $v$ escapes to infinity.

Comment: is $F$ full rank?